# Is there a way to import my favorites bar from Firefox to Internet Explorer 9

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-9

I have a favorites bar from firefox and i want to replicate that to IE 9.  Is there a ways to do this without having to add each site one by one?

Answer (score 0):

the quickest way ist to use drag&drop - drag your link from the favbar in FF to the favbar in IE

Answer (score 0):

**MANUAL INSTRUCTIONS:**

First export your favourites in Firefox:

1. In Firefox, click on the Firefox button -> Bookmarks.
2. Click on Import and Backup -> Export bookmarks to HTML.
3. Save it anywhere (remember where, though).

Then import them in Internet Explorer:

1. In Internet Explorer, press Alt to show the menu bar and go to File -> Import and Export.
2. Select the "Import from a file". Press Next.
3. Tick the box that says Favourites. Press Next.
4. Click on Browse and the find and select the bookmarks file that you exported from Firefox. Press Next.
5. Select your destination folder. Press Import. Press Finish.

**AUTOMATED INSTRUCTIONS:**

1. In Internet Explorer, press Alt to show the menu bar and go to File -> Import and Export.
2. Click on Import from another browser.
3. Tick Firefox and click Import.